# Reading and Extracting only Required Contents from all type of documents in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, .doc

I am trying to build a system in C#.NET / MVC / ASP.NET, where we have 1000s of different documents in .doc, .xls, .pdf, .txt etc and those are movie / serial scripts for subtitle and dubbing.

I have to extract the actual content i.e. dialogues, exclude unwanted text from all templates and count number of lines / paragraphs are spoken by different characters in a single script.

Issue is here, there is no predefined / concrete format of documents and said we can't define that too, since they come from various countries / states and each has different way of writing scripts.

If someone already have developed this type of system or used any third party opensource or paid API, would be really grateful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well n gud. Your project sounds quite interesting. But in order to help you we want to know what you have tried?

Comment: Asish, I have only tried to read a word file using .NET for POC with using hard coded text to identify Characters / Segments and number of lines / paragraph.

Comment: So you are trying something like [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwie39_qxsPQAhXMO48KHX0tAbgQFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbrel.co.uk%2Fpdfs%2FAV_PhD.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGp02UGOsieV6FnNmB7-PoV6_yXyw&bvm=bv.139782543,d.c2I&cad=rja) ?

Comment: Yes as per PDF looks similar, I could not see completely, but here is my problem statement with example How to extract right content from a document / file where no concrete / predefined format is available.
For e.g. there is a dialogue script which has content where a Character name is P, and he speaks dialogue:
SC 01 - EXT. WHEELIEVILLE & DRIVING SCHOOL - DAY
We MOVE IN toward ROBERTO’S DRIVING SCHOOL and its test track. Beyond is the hill-hugging town of WHEELIEVILLE. EDDIE AND 
So question is how to make a system which can extract any type of content from any document.

Comment: Hi All,I have completed this project with 95% accuracy, so if some one needs help, happy to help. Let me know